# Call class functions from another class?

Tags: c++, class

Say I have two classes One, the Foo class, interfaces with the user, and a Bar class that actually does stuff with any input received.  Foo has an object of type Bar within it so it can call the Bar class's method when Foo receives input from the user, passing any data it receives to the "bar::onEvent()" function for processing.

From there the Bar method, onEvent(), calls a bunch of other methods depending on what data was passed.  These methods may then, in certain situations, need to call interface methods from the Foo class, like output or exit type functions.

Basically it goes, Foo gets User Input, passes that data to Bar, Bar handles that input, Bar sends data back to for, if applicable, for output.  Foo handles receiving and sending data from/to the user, while Bar handles the actual processing of the data.

So Foo is constantly checking for input, when it's received, it's passed from Foo, to Bar to be processed.  In some cases Bar may need to send new data back to Foo for output.

This is a dumbed down version of what I need to do.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Bar bar;
    void genericFunctionSimulatingInput(char* data)
    {
        //when input is received, call bar class to handle the logic
        while(data == someKindOfInput)
        {
            bar::onEvent(data);
        }
    }
    void spitOut(char* data);
};

class Bar
{
    void onEvent(char* data)
    {
        //do something with data
        //here the modified data needs to be sent back to the user(could be a mathematical operation  
        //or something.  But what I really need to call is "bu::spitOut(data);", not 
        Foo::spitOut(data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    //create the Foo object that I'll be using throughout
    Foo bu;
    //call the main loop function that will act as the heart of the code
    bu.genericFunctionSimulatingInput("fdklafjdasl");
    return 0;
}
```

I need Bar to be calling functions from the already existing Foo object that I created in the main function, which I called bu, but I have no idea how to get the bu object into the bar objects scope.

I just need the bar object within the bu object to be aware of the bu object that it resides in.

How would I go about doing this?  Would I have to somehow pass in the reference, of bu, into the bar.onEvent(); method?  And then to all subsequent methods called by this initial method?  If so how would I go about doing this?

I understand how to do it if I had created them both within the main function.  Just pass &bu, but from within bu itself?  I haven't a clue how I'd do this.

I know this is a really abstract example but I hope I've explained enough to where your imaginations can do the rest.  If not I'll try to better explain it.

I just need Bu's Bar class to be able to access bu's functions.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your design - you have some weird circular issues going.  maybe rethink you approach?

Comment: A cleaner way to do this would be to ask Bar to return the needed data. Foo could then "spit out" that data, or ask another class Baz to do it. This is called the Model-View-Controller pattern, Foo being the Cotnroller, Bar the Model, and Baz the view. (just saying for your information, keeping is as it is is probably the best decision for now, but be aware that "MVC" exists.)

Comment: Good thinking.  I'm going to scrap this model and try something else.  This is just not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Foo &foo)
        : m_foo(foo)
        { }

    void onEvent();

private:
    Foo &m_foo;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
        : m_bar(*this)
        { }


    void onEvent()
        {
            m_bar.onEvent();
        }

    void onEventDone()
        {
        }

private:
    Bar m_bar;
};
```

The functions in `Bar` calling functions in `Foo` have to be defined after `Foo` has been properly defined. So they can't be inline in `Bar`.

```
void Bar::onEvent();
{
    // Do stuff
    m_foo.onEventDone();
}
```

If you want the methods in Bar of Foo to be private, then make them friend of each other:

```
class Bar
{
    friend class Foo;
    // ...
```

and

```
class Foo
{
    friend class Bar;
    // ...
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.  I knew there had to be a simple explanation for this.

Comment: ok, I'm having a bit of a problem.  I have Foo inside a header file which I #include into Bar.cpp.  When I type out "Foo &m_foo;" I get an error and I don't understand why.  Intellisense says that Foo is indeed a class type that it recognizes, but it won't let me make m_foo a reference or pointer.  When I mouse over m_foo, intellisense shows "<error type> &Bar::m_foo" but it works just fine when I make it a normal object?

Comment: Well I get about a million compiler errors, but the main one for this is that on the line  "Foo &foo" it says I'm missing a ; before the &.  Like it's not realizing Foo is a class.  Edit:  Nevermind, forgot a colon.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
class Bar
{
public:
    void onEvent(char* data)
    {
        //do something with data
        //here the modified data needs to be sent back to the user(could be a mathematical operation  
        //or something.  But what I really need to call is "bu::spitOut(data);", not 
        Foo::spitOut(data);
    }
};
```

write

```
class Bar
{
 public:
    void onEvent(Foo& foo, char* data)
    {
        //do something with data
        //here the modified data needs to be sent back to the user(could be a mathematical operation  
        //or something.  But what I really need to call is "bu::spitOut(data);", not 
        foo.spitOut(data);
    }
};
```

instead of

```
 bar::onEvent(data);
```

write

```
  bar.onEvent( *this, data );
```

always try to decouple classes as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks much.  The "this" keyword is exactly what I needed.